# npm package.json dependencies - for a library component

Tags: npm, package.json

Lets say I am working on a library that will be consumed by other developers. MyPackage has a dependency on moment. The developer that consumes my package also has a dependency on moment. So moment will exist as a "dependency" in both library package.json and application package.json (and thus get packaged twice). Is there a way to package it just once? If the consumer has it, use theirs, else use mine?

Comment: What if they depend on a different version of it than you do? Just handle your own dependencies, don't worry about everyone else's.

Comment: I realize. If we standardize on a version may beven we can reduce the final payload if we don't have to package everything multiple times. Moment is just one of many dependencies

Comment: Do you actually have a problem with output file sizes or something? This seems a lot like premature optimisation. That said if it's only for internal use and everyone's happy to always use the same version, you could make a peer dependency https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Comment: Yes - its a corporate website and we can standardize on one version - we also need to keep the final page payload to a minimum so definitely need to reduce bloat wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's already happening by default on fresh installs if dependency ranges match.

npm v>=3 *does* gang the dependencies, depending on the installation order and depth, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-nondet).

Also, if you kept working on the same folder for a while, there might be some cruft, which could be wiped using `npm dedupe`, see [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-dupe).

In theory, `moment` should not be duplicated if both your library and developer's library are consuming the same version ranges of it. At least if `npm dedupe` is called or `node_modules` are wiped and `npm i`-nstalled.